# Google Cloud Logging setting the current resource dynamically in VM

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

wondering if anyone knows a solution to my issue. When running the following code within a VM on the GCP, the log seems to go to the `Global` resource type.

```py
from google.cloud import logging as cloudlogging

CLOUD_LOGGER_NAME = "nicee_test_logger"

log_client = cloudlogging.Client()
log_client.get_default_handler()
log_client.setup_logging()
cloud_logger = log_client.logger(CLOUD_LOGGER_NAME)

cloud_logger.log_struct(
  {
    "method": "<module>",
    "message": "This is message overwrite",
    "amount_failed": 10,
    "errors": [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
    ],
    "amount_transfered": 10
  }, severity="INFO"
)
```

When I look in the Logging UI and use the `resource.type="GLOBAL"` the `{"foo": "bar"}` log shows up as a `jsonPayload`. I want this to be under the `VM` resource type. [image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYznh.png)

I tried different methods of logging and the `log_struct` is the most workable for me.

Is there a way to get the resource dynamically and still be able to use the `log_struct` method?

Answer (score 0):

I dug in the Go library and I found only 4 possible types allowed when you use the library:

```
var resourceInfo = map[string]struct{ rtype, label string }{
    "organizations":   {"organization", "organization_id"},
    "folders":         {"folder", "folder_id"},
    "projects":        {"project", "project_id"},
    "billingAccounts": {"billing_account", "account_id"},
}
```

The other types are built-in and you can't use them. However, you can customize your LogName if you want and filter on that instead of resource type.